# Dimensions when subtracting numpy.ndarray() that are column vector (dimension [m,1])

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am subtracting 2 numpy.ndarrays *h* and *y* with shape of (47,1) and (47,) respectively. When I use python to subtract both of the next functions return an array of shape (47,47). I know that mathematically this operation should keep the dimensions of the input arrays, but its not working that way.

The operations I used are:

```
e = h - y
e = np.subtract(h,y)
```

Is that something about how numpy does the operations, or should I be using other types of operations for this? How do I fix it so that the dimensions of the resulting array match with the correct ones mathematically?

Comment: That is called `broadcasting`.  What you got was an `outer` subtraction.  Effectively a (1,47) with a (47,1).  What is the "mathematically" correct operation with the dimensions differ?

Answer (score 0):

The shape of `h` and `y` should be identical for elementwise subtraction as you mentioned.
The both methods you describe are identical.
The following code works

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]])

print(a.shape)    # (7,)
print(b.shape)    # (1,7)

c = a-b          # or np.subtract(a,b)
print(c.shape)   # (1,7)
print(c)         # [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Maybe one of ndarrays is transposed. The shape of `a-b.T` is (7,7) as you described.

### Edit

I forgot the fact that you described a column vector.
In this case the following would do the trick for elementwise subtraction:

```
h.T-y
```